# Loop through a list on Drool rules

Tags: java, drools

I  need to write a rule using Drool that will validate that the phone number is valid US number (for the sake of this answer we can use this regex "^([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$")

The object structure is like this:

```
{
  "name": {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Smith"},
  "phone": [{"phoneType": "mobile", "phoneNumber":"123456789"}],
  "dob":"01/01/2000"
}
```

Because phone is a list, I don't know how to loop and validate this object. For instance the validation for "dob" field looks something like this:

```
rule "RuleId: Drool01, Validate dob"
  when
     $user: user(dob != null)
     user(dob not matches "(?:0[1-9]|1[012])" from $user
  then
    modify($user){setDob(null)};
```

I appreciate any help on this. I apologize if this is very basic but I literally just started to use Drools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume these models (irrelevant bits omitted; assume getters and setters):

```
class User {
  private Name name; // Name model not shown, not relevant to this question
  private Phone phone;
  private String dob;
}
class Phone {
  private String phoneType;
  private String phoneNumber;
}
```

We can then write a rule like this:

```
rule "Invalid Phone Number"
when
  $user: User( $phoneNumbers: phone )
  exists( Phone( phoneNumber not matches "^([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$" ) from $phoneNumbers)
then
  // $user has at least 1 phone number which doesn't match the pattern
end
```

This rule is useful when we only need to know that there exists a bad value. It gets a little more interesting if we actually need to get those bad values (eg. if we want to report out a better error message.)

If we want to trigger the consequences for *each* bad phone number (eg. if there are 3 phone numbers and 2 are bad, we want to trigger the "then" twice) we could do like this:

```
rule "Invalid Phone Number - trigger for each"
when
  $user: User( $phoneNumbers: phone )
  $badPhone: Phone( phoneNumber not matches "^([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$") from $phoneNumbers
then
  // here $badPhone will be a phone number for $user that doesn't match the pattern
end
```

You might want to write a rule like this if you want to do something for each bad phone number individually. Consider maybe if we were doing "verified" phone numbers -- for example, they text you passcode that you have to use to verify your phone number; in this case you could text each phone number, one-by-one, to go through this verification process.

Alternatively we could just collect up all of the bad phone numbers and trigger the consequences once for all of those numbers, collectively.

```
rule "Invalid Phone Number - trigger once for all"
when
  $user: User( $phoneNumbers: phone )
  $badNumbers: List( size > 0 ) from collect (
      Phone( phoneNumber not matches "^([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$") from $phoneNumbers
  )
then
  // $badNumbers is a list of all of the Phone objects that don't match
  // the pattern and belong to $user
end
```